# jmeterで3万/1分のhttpリクエストを5分間継続するとBackingStoreExceptionが発生する

Tags: exception

jmeterを使用した負荷検証中をしている最中

jmeterで1分間に1万のhttpリクエストを発行するjmeterのスクリプトを
下記のように突き放しで3回*10回(分)実行しています。

```
for i in 10
do
 jmeter -t 10000request.jmx >> jmeter.log &
 jmeter -t 10000request.jmx >> jmeter.log &
 jmeter -t 10000request.jmx >> jmeter.log &
 sleep 60
done
```

3分(回)目当たりで下記のWARNINGが頻発します。

```
java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld WARNING: 
  Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.
```

原因がわからず、困窮しており、想定通りの負荷がかけられません。

原因と対策をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 翻訳文：WebSphere Application Serverの開始に使用されている非ルートIDには、user_homeディレクトリーがありません。したがって、この非ルートIDはルートユーザーの「/etc/.java/.systemPrefs」にアクセスできません。これにより、profile_root / logs / server_name / systemout.logに30秒ごとに前述の警告メッセージが生成されます。　原文参照：https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/starting-websphere-application-server-gives-warning-message-could-not-lock-user-prefs

Comment: マルチポスト: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112181/backingstoreexception-occurs-when-30-000-1-minute-http-request-continues-on-jm

Comment: 認識しております。解決内容を共有致します。

Answer (score 1):

user_homeの存在しないユーザのrootユーザで実行している事が原因でした。
実際のリクエスト数を確認すると意図したリクエスト数で負荷をかる事ができていました。

この警告はuser_homeの存在するユーザで実行する事で回避する事ができました。